# Python: Selenium with tor proxy wont allow connection

Tags: python, selenium

When i try to connect to the tor proxy via my firefox selenium bot i get an error message "The Proxy server is refusing connections"

> Error Message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmZoK.png

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")

user_agent = "Firefox"
proxy_ip = "127.0.0.1"
proxy_port = 9050

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", proxy_ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", proxy_port)
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,capabilities=firefox_capabilities,firefox_profile=profile)
def interactWithSite(driver):
    driver.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
interactWithSite(driver)
```

Comment: If you're using `proxy_type 1` (socks) you don't need to set `http/s`, `ssl`, `ftp` as well; also the port should be an int (`9050`, not `"9050"`); remove the `str` calls for IP and port.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Did you set socks version? `profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)`; first confirm that your Tor proxy is functioning correctly (perhaps using your regular Firefox browser) and then make sure the FirefoxProfile in your code yields the same settings in the browser.

Comment: still not working its still not allowing me to connect even by adding that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: You need to have Tor Browser running in the background to connect to the tor browser network/proxy with your FireFox user agent/browser.